# How do I call event on a dynamically added element with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building an Application with PhoneGap. The application has content pulled from an outside resource. Within the content I pull, there are URLs. Since I load the content in my html dynamically, the href does not exist when the page is created. What I need is a way to find that dynamically added href once the content is loaded, and call a function on it when clicked.

Here is part of the html page where the content is placed, specifically in the `#page-content div`:

```
<div data-role="content">
    <div id="page-title"></div>
    <div id="page-region"></div>
    <div id="page-content"></div>

</div>
```

Once the page is loaded with the content, the html page changes to this:

```
    <div data-role="content" class="ui-content" role="main">
        <div id="page-title">Mtg: Switchboard and Panelboard Basics: A Tour of the Eaton Hayward Facility<br></div>
        <div id="page-region">Oakland/East Bay<br></div>
        <div id="page-content"><p>THURSDAY February 20, 2014<br>


 OEB Industry Applications Chapter<br>
    - construction, differences, functions, features …<br>
    Speakers: Joseph Burnett, Jason Maffioli, Kendyl Brown, and Bob Salter, Eaton<br>
    Time: Light Dinner at 5:30 PM; Short Presentation at 6:00PM; Tours at 6:30 PM<br>
    Cost: none<br>
    Place:<br>
    Web: <a href="http://www.ThisIsTheUrlINeed.com"> www.ThisIsTheUrlINeed.com  </a></p>
    <p>We will discuss Basics of switchboard construction, functions and features, some     of the basic “dos and don’ts” related to Switchboard specification, differences between Switchboards and Panelboards, some of the differences and similarities between switchboards and <span id="more-4060"></span>switchgear, and application limitations. The short presentation will be followed by a tour where attendees can see first-hand the basic building blocks, and how panelboards and switchboards are built.</p>
<br></div>

    </div>
```

The function I wrote/found to try and grab the href is:

```
    $('#page-content').on('click','a', function(){
        console.log(this);
        currentPage = $(this).attr('href');
        window.open(currentPage, '_blank', 'location=yes')
    });
```

Nothing appears in the `console.log` when I run it. I read that `.on` should be used for situations like this, so I am stumped as to what to do next.

Edit, here is the function I am using to populate the html page:

```
function IE_navigate(index) {

    Bindex = index;

    $.mobile.changePage('#eventPage', 'slidefade');

    $.each(data, function(i,item){
        if (i == Bindex) {
              //Clear if page was previously populated


              //Populate page
              $('#page-title').html(item.title + "<br />");
              $('#page-region').html(item.Region + "<br />");
              $('#page-content').html(item.fullInfo + "<br />");



              return false
        }
    });
};
```

Edit: SOLUTION Thanks to a combination of the two answers below (and all the help from everyone else!) here is how I was able to get this problem to work:

```
function IE_navigate(index) {

    Bindex = index;

    $.mobile.changePage('#eventPage', 'slidefade');

    $.each(data, function(i,item){
        if (i == Bindex) {
              //Clear if page was previously populated


              //Populate page
              $('#page-title').html(item.title + "<br />");
              $('#page-region').html(item.Region + "<br />");
              $('#page-content').html(item.fullInfo + "<br />");

              $(this).ready(function(e) {
                  $('#page-content').on('click','a', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                     console.log(this)
                    currentPage = $(this).attr('href');
                   window.open(currentPage, '_system', 'location=yes')
               });
              });
             // return false;

              return false
        }
    });
};
```

Basically, the function needed to come after the content was loaded. My original method of implementation was not differentiating between the content before or after it was populated. Thanks again everyone!

Comment: Did you miss the semicolon after `console.log(this)` just here by copy paste?

Comment: i think you also need to add preventdefault see here: http://jsfiddle.net/a6NJk/637/

Comment: Also note `#page-content` should be nearest static container

Comment: I suspect the same as AwladLiton, page reload on click?

Comment: here is another demo :  http://jsfiddle.net/a6NJk/641/

Comment: @Sebsemillia Yes i missed that accidentally, sorry!

Comment: @procrastinator Yes, no error :/

Comment: @satpal - can you explain nearest static container?

Comment: @AwladLiton- added, with no result

Comment: @Bacon2305 : did you test my answer?

Comment: @AwladLiton I did, both in a web browser and side-loaded onto the app with no luck. I added the function I use to populate the page in case that is the problem.

Comment: @procrastinator by page reload on click, do you mean the action that results from the click or a possible code solution?

Comment: @Bacon2305 I meant "a possible error". Nevermind :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to preventDefault action.

I have tried with sample data.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/a6NJk/642/

Jquery:

```
$('#page-content').on('click','a', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(this);
        currentPage = $(this).attr('href');
        window.open(currentPage, '_blank', 'location=yes')
    });
//this function for generating dynamic html
$("#bb").click(function(){
   $("#page-content").append("Web: <a href=\"http://www.ThisIsTheUrlINeed.com\">www.ThisIsTheUrlINeed.com  </a>");

})
```

Comment: You should also add the missing semicolons. Don't trust ASI.

Comment: Awlad - I marked your answer as correct because it is! Although placement was key...the ajax answer below led me to place the code elsewhere in the code to get it to work correctly. Thanks again for you input!

Answer (score 0):

The function you wrote/found to try and grab the href must be run *after* the page is populated with external content.

e.g

```
$.ajax({

    url: 'http://external/foobar.html',
    success: function( data, status, xhr ) {

         // stuff data in #page-content and so on    
         // ...and when the anchor is in DOM;

         $('#page-content').find('a').click(function(){

              dooTheDoo($this.attr('href'));

         });
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you explain what to add to the success part a bit more? I replaced the url: with the URL of the content page and added a console.log in place of dooTheDoo but it didn't work. Should I add something else in the "stuff data in #page-content" part?

Comment: Thank you for your solution - for my specific need, this solution worked in the sense that I re-thought where to implement the code. You were absolutely correct that the function needed to run after the page loaded.